# how to get data from {} in graphql

Tags: django, reactjs, graphql

I want to get data about user addinfo(bool value).

when i do console.log(data.user), i can get data.user referred to below picture.
[image]

if when i do console.log(data.user.user), it shows that user is undefined referred to below picture.
[image]

```
{
  user(token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImI3ZTA5YmVhOTAzNzQ3ODQiLCJleHAiOjE1NjM4OTcxNzksIm9yaWdJYXQiOjE1NjM4OTY4Nzl9.QFB58dAvqIC9RBBohN1b3TdR542dBZEcXOG1MSTqAQQ") {
    user {
      id
      addinfo
    }
  }
}
```

this code show that

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "user": {
        "id": "4",
        "addinfo": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code that calls for the data.  The resolver, schema, react, everything.  This could be one of many problems but it seems that you aren't using return / await or any other async code.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the rest of your code, but if the code is fetching your users, there is a time before the request comes back where your user has not been fetched yet. It looks like your screenshot shows this. There is an `undefined` before the successful object.

You need to ensure that the data has come back first be checking if the data prop is truthy or some other way to check if the promise has completed yet.

ie

```
if (!data.user) return 'Loading...';
return (
  <Switch>
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

In GraphQL I'm getting user info using e.g. below code:

```
async getUser(id) {
    const result = await this.api.query({
        query: gql(getUser),
        variables: {
            id,
        },
    });

    return result.data.getUser || null;
}
```

I'm invoking it by:

```
const user = await userService.getUser(id);
```

and I do have access to user properties. 
Maybe you're trying to get user data before they are retrieved and available?